# Which statistical method to use? Two way ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

I need some help determine which statistical method is best to use:
In a mine expansion a forest is destroyed. Prior to the expansion 10 plots were established to measure the deadwood volumes.

Three methods are used in a restoration effort to mimic the deadwood volumes of the destroyed forest - where nothing is added (10 plots), 30 logs are added (10 plots) or 80 logs are added (10 plots).

Which treatment comes closest to the values of the destroyed forest? What statistical method would I use? I am thinking of a two way ANOVA and TukeysHSD test, but wonder if there is anything more powerful or better to use?

Comment: Why a *two*-way ANOVA? What are the two "ways" or dimensions? I only see one, the treatment being "number of logs added to the plot". What would be your other treatment that makes up the two-way ANOVA?

Comment: I thought of the different number of logs as different treatments "0 logs added", "30 logs added" or "80 logs added" - but perhaps I'm on the wrong track. So would it work with a one way anova?

Comment: If you have only one type of treatment (as it seems to be the case here) it's a one-way ANOVA. In order to have a two-way ANOVA, you would need two types of treatment. Ex: "# logs added" and, say, "altitude level of the area where logs are added". In that case the two-way ANOVA allows you to analyze the effect on the response of the different possible combinations of "# logs added" and "altitude".